# Can I use G-Drive on a Cloud Website?

Tags: google-drive-api

I wondering create a Cloud website, that offers cloud storage for users to have their images, videos... safe in cloud, and I'm thinking to use a G-Drive account for it, since I have a good space on my Google Account. But I read Google Terms, and I'm not sure if this is allowed by Google or a legal thing.

> If you are using our Services on behalf of a business, that business
>   accepts these terms. It will hold harmless and indemnify Google and
>   its affiliates, officers, agents, and employees from any claim, suit
>   or action arising from or related to the use of the Services or
>   violation of these terms, including any liability or expense arising
>   from claims, losses, damages, suits, judgments, litigation costs and
>   attorneys’ fees.

Does anyone know something about it? Will I have problems if I go on with this project?

My apologies, I'm not sure if this kind of question it's allowed here, so forgive me if it's not.

Comment: Don't think Google Drive is best for a project/company storage. You're better of going for [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) or [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/)

Comment: Well, since G-Drive has a good API, and I have an account with unlimited storage, I would like to start from there ... then obviously I would migrate to some other service if things start growing up

Comment: Maybe with a very small scale project, GDrive will do. But, I see you having problems with QPS read/writes quota problems when your userbase starts growing.

Comment: Well at this time I should already have something more solid ... the only thing that worries me, is the fact that I don't know if it's something illegal, since google isn't clear about it